# Changing Selected Chart's Border Color

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

If I record an Excel macro to change the border color of a chart, then VBA returns

```
Sub change_bordercolor()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

so I wanted to code to change the border color of not the `"Chart 1"` but a currently selected chart as follows.

```
Sub change_bordercolor()
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

but this returns the 438 runtime error. Where do I need to change to use the `Selection` instead of the `"Chart 1?`"

Comment: I found Selecting Charts to be a lot more hassle than its worth, more of a hassle than normal `.Select` issues. Is it absolutely necessary to have the Chart selected? And to just run the code on a single Chart?

Comment: Yes. I hope to use the ```selection```. My ```sub``` inserts new charts via, for example, ```ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlXYScatter).Select``` and then does some micromanagements such as ```ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)
```. I want to add one more line to change the border color of the new charts while adding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the bordercolor of the **Active Chart you must have selected** you can use this code:

```
Sub Macro1()

If Application.ActiveChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub


With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Replace(Application.ActiveChart.Name, ActiveSheet.Name & " ", "")).Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With

End Sub
```

I've set it up to change border color to green, but you can adapt it to your needs. This is how it works:

[image]

It changes border color of **active selected chart**.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask one more? This code brings the ```"Chart 1"``` part from the ```Application.ActiveChart.Name```, but is the ```Application``` in front of the ```ActiveChart``` necessary? I see ```Application.ActiveSheet``` sometimes and just ```ActiveSheet``` sometimes, but when do I need it specifically?

Comment: Nope, it's not really needed in this case. You just need the object application if you are working with different instances of Excel (not in this case). I use it to benefit from [Intellisense](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/intellisense.htm) and code faster, but it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach:

```
Sub ChangeBorderColor()
  If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveChart.ChartArea.Format.Line
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      .Transparency = 0
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the simplest approach is ```ActiveChart.ChartArea.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)```.